# Is it possible to obtain an array of x values from an implicit function of x in python?

Tags: python, implicit

I am trying to obtain a function of x(y) instead of y(x), but the function itself in terms of x is an implicit function. Is there a way that I can return the x value base on a range of y? Or is it possible to extrapolate a set of x,y values at x much greater than 10^7?

edit1: changed the x and y to make it more sensible

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy import interpolate


df = .1
a = 300


y = np.arange(1, a,df)          
def x (y):
    try:
        x = y*(a-1)**(3/2)/(a-y)**(3/2)
        return x                
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        return 0
plt.loglog(x(y),y,'b')
```

[image: Loglog plot of the function]

Follow up:
Turns out interp1d can also be used for extrapolation

```
from scipy import interpolate
inte = interpolate.interp1d(x(y),y, fill_value='extrapolate')
ynew = np.arange(299,300,1e-5)
xnew = f(ynew)
plt.loglog(x(y),y,xnew,ynew)
```

[image: extrapolation result]

Comment: "is it possible to extrapolate" yes have you searched for it? Same for interpolation.

Comment: @Julien Thanks, turns out extrapolation using interp1d works. It was returning weird complex values for a bit, turns out I used the wrong bound for the ynew.